# What is the proper way to get current inflation rate with solana web3.js

Tags: web3.js, rpc, supply

I'm attempting to get the current total network inflation rate in my application. I thought that historically there was a method for this provided by web3.js, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

The rpc does provide a method to handle this:

```
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"getInflationRate"}
~~
{
  jsonrpc: '2.0',
  result: {
    epoch: 403,
    foundation: 0,
    total: 0.06381484839551996,
    validator: 0.06381484839551996
  },
  id: '3f64ef5f-b8cf-4fed-beb4-d30511daddb7'
}
```

But how can I get this same data from web3.js? There's doesn't seem to be a `getInflationRate` method.

Answer (score 3):

Was using a very old version of solana-web3.js, updated to the latest, and the `getInflationRate` method was available.